# Is there a way top quickly find all the class whose base class is A

Tags: c#, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Visual Studio: How do I show all classes inherited from a base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282377/visual-studio-how-do-i-show-all-classes-inherited-from-a-base-class)
>   [Get all derived types of a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857705/get-all-derived-types-of-a-type)

In visual studio, I am wondering if I can quickly find all the classes whose base is class A?

For example,

I know B derived from A, can I find all other classes derived from A?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get all derived types of a type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857705/get-all-derived-types-of-a-type), [Tool to Show Class Hierarchies in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384406/tool-to-show-class-hierarchies-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope [ReSharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282377/visual-studio-how-do-i-show-all-classes-inherited-from-a-base-class/282386#282386) helps